# Rails - Activestorage causing rails configuration failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, rails-activestorage

I am having an issue trying to deploy my app to heroku with rails active storage. In development I have no issues using 
`config.active_storage.service = :local`
and all works as it should. 
However in my `production.rb` file I have set `config.active_storage.service = :amazon` 
and followed the set up guides.

My `storage.yml`is as follows:

```
  test:
    service: Disk
    root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

  local:
    service: Disk
    root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

 amazon:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
    secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
    region: <%= ENV['S3_REGION'] %>
    bucket: <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] %>
```

When I run git push heroku master, the app will deploy, but the following error will appear in the logs: "Detecting rails configuration failed".

I am unable to open the app and the herkou log will display the following error: "Missing configuration for the :amazon Active Storage service. Configurations available for [:test]".

This same error occurs if I change 
    `config.active_storage.service = :amazon` 
to 
    `config.active_storage.service = :local`
however if I change it to 
    `config.active_storage.service = :test`

the app will deploy without error and I am able to open the app and upload files as expected.

I have trawled the web but haven't seen anyone else with this error, so any comments or thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your using to store your environment variables? Figaro or something else?

Comment: variables are stored in heroku config vars

Comment: When you run `$ heroku config`, do all of your env variables show up? With the correct name?

Comment: Yeah they show up

Comment: Sounds like you're running in test environment. Perhaps one of your config vars is setting rails env or rack env to test. Can you check?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the indentation in storage.yml
test: local: are indented one space, and amazon: is indented two spaces.

I had the same problem, and it was hard to notice an extra space. In YAML the spaces matter, but Ruby devs are not accustomed to having the spaces matter.